# Poco HTTP Post Request with large body

Tags: c++, http, poco

I try to do a POST Request with Poco, which is just working fine.
When my request body gets huge (picture upload), I always get an exception.

exception.what() says just "I/O Error".

```
req.setContentLength(body.length());
std::ostream &os = session.sendRequest(req);
os << body;
```

That's how I send the request body.

What can be the reason?
Or how can I debug that?